# MySQL Procedure With Multiple Updates

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? : -
The following code works on my local server - executed using MySQL workbench: -

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `namechange`(IN oldname VARCHAR(20),IN newname VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
UPDATE liquidfinger.users SET username = newname WHERE username = oldname LIMIT 1;
UPDATE liquidfinger.markers SET username = newname WHERE username = oldname;
UPDATE liquidfinger.photos SET user = newname WHERE user = oldname;
UPDATE liquidfinger.mail SET to_name = newname WHERE to_name = oldname;
UPDATE liquidfinger.mail SET from_name = newname WHERE from_name = oldname;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I can't create the procedure on my website, hosted by GoDaddy and using phpMyAdmin.
The error message I get back reads: -

> "MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'UPDATE liquidfinger.markers SET username = newname
>   WHERE username = oldname; UP' at line 3"

The second update is always the point at which the problem begins - so that it doesn't like more than one update.
The GoDaddy MySQL server version is: -Server version: 5.5.41-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
The latest MySQL version is 5.6.25

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no error at my end, procedure executed well...

Comment: can you try by removing   DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`  from the procedure?

Comment: Aman - you don't get control over that in the form provided by phpMyAdmin. The only two options are 'Definer' and 'Invoker'.

Comment: try using SQL tab and create it as you run a query..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it to work. I tried using the SQL tab in phpMyAdmin before and it didn't work, but I tried it again omitting "DEFINER= . ." and it worked. So I can only conclude there is some sort of bug in phpMyAdmin(?) But previously I have tried exporting and importing sql files using MySQL workbench - and that didn't work either(?)
Case closed - I'm not sure if I should tick my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

When using the form in phpMyAdmin to create a procedure, you must put `BEGIN` as the first statement and `END` as the last statement. The SQL generated by phpMyAdmin doesn't automatically insert those statements in a multi-statement procedure, so there will be a syntax error if you don't put them in the definition.

So the code in the "Definition" textbox should look like this:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE liquidfinger.users SET username = newname WHERE username = oldname LIMIT 1;
UPDATE liquidfinger.markers SET username = newname WHERE username = oldname;
END
```